# Ender 3 v2 won't boot up after installing Sprite extruder

Tags: troubleshooting

I installed a Sprite direct drive extruder everything went together fine but it would give a mintemp error code and say to restart. After I checked all the wiring again and restarted it 10 times no change. So I replaced the temperature sensor, no change. It still wasn't even reading room temp.

So I went thru and unplugged each connection and put it right back thinking maybe a bad connection. I restarted the printer again and now it goes to the boot screen and stays there no line going across or anything. I don't know what to try next any help would be appreciated.